# Kentico SMTP: use TLS instead of SSL

Tags: ssl, smtp, kentico

I have got configuration settings from my provider how to connect to POP3/SMTP server. It works perfectly in Outlook, but it doesn't work with Kentico (Azure hosted).

*Note: In case of Gmail SMTP settings (with SSL enabled) Kentico works perfectly.*

In Kentico I use the following configuration (below) but I don't have the possiblity to adjust the protocol (TLS is important in my case) and the port number (587).

- smtp server - email.active24.com
- use ssl - checked
- login - XXX@YYY.ZZZ
- password - NNN

The error (see below) contains two messages:

- Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
- Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 81.95.97.101:25

---

```
Message: Failure sending mail.

Exception type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Stack trace: 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at CMS.EmailEngine.EmailProvider.SendEmailInternal(String siteName, MailMessage message, SMTPServerInfo smtpServer)
at CMS.EmailEngine.EmailSender.SendTestEmail(String siteName, EmailMessage message, SMTPServerInfo smtpServer)
at CMSModules_System_System_Email.SendEmail() in C:\Projects\Kentico\_install\CMS\CMSModules\System\System_Email.aspx.cs:line 122
at CMSModules_System_System_Email.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Kentico\_install\CMS\CMSModules\System\System_Email.aspx.cs:line 78

Message: Unable to connect to the remote server

Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Stack trace: 
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 81.95.97.101:25

Exception type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Stack trace: 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

I need to set the following configuration:

[image]

Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is to use the smtp server name together with the port number like:

```
email.active24.com:587
```